# sql conversion of data types cast and convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I have two columns in my table: `AmountIncl_LC`, `AmountExcl_LC` which are `nvarchar` data type.

Now O want to change data type of these two columns and sum two columns into a  one column result us.

```
select cast(AmountIncl_LC as int)int [AmountIncl_LC] 
from dbo.table2
```

I used the above query and it is throwing me an error saying

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AmountIncl_LC'.

Comment: amounts should not be varchar....

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: `select cast(AmountIncl_LC as int) [AmountIncl_LC] 
from dbo.table2` , therefore, removing `int` behind `cast`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select cast(AmountIncl_LC as numeric(16,8))+cast(AmountExcl_LC as numeric(16,8)) from dbo.table2
```

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7000.00000' to data type int.again error

Comment: use numeric instead of int

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
it gave me an error like above

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b7508/3 - check here, it should work definetely

Answer (score 0):

try this

`select cast(AmountIncl_LC as int)+cast(AmountExcl_LC as int) from dbo.table2`

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't contain all the details. The DB seems to hold ints in decimal format stored as Nvarchar, which in the first place isn't a great approach. You should try cast:

```
select try_cast(AmountIncl_LC as decimal)+try_cast(AmountExcl_LC as decimal) from dbo.table2
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST function could be **helpful** to change the data type while Querying, and use the
addition operator "+" to add both columns. Further, you can use the "AS" command to create a new column ;

As far as my understanding, the only error in your code is *variable mismatch* and *Syntax error*;

```
select CAST(AmountIncl_LC AS int) + CAST(AmountExcl_LC AS int) as New_Column from dbo.table2;
```